# Firefox PDF.js viewer showing μ for non-checked radio buttons and λ for checked radio buttons in a TCPDF generated PDF document

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am stuck in a weird problem. I used TCPDF PHP library and set the encoding to "UTF-8" and now the PDF it is generating contains μ for non-checked radio buttons and λ for checked radio buttons when being viewed in Firefox PDF.js

Here is the URL of such a PDF I am working upon: http://lab.hashbyte.com/form-pdf-mailer/pdf/form_52527caf72ced.pdf

The problem doesn't happen in `Adobe Reader`, `PDF XChange Viewer`, `Gnome Document Viewer` or `Google Drive PDF Viewer`. It only happens in `Firefox's PDF.js` and I have no clue why

Please help me in this regard since the application users would be most probably general audience and to make it work in PDF.js is really important.

The PDF contains German language and the encoding is set to "UTF-8".
[image: PDF.js Preview]

[image: Adobe Reader Preview]

Comment: I just inspected your PDF. The appearance streams of the radio buttons indeed contain the instructions to print an l or m (154 and 155 as octal character codes) using the /ZapfDingbats font. ZapfDingbats at those codes indeed has radio button symbols, but the Symbol Set in those positions has lambda and mu. PDF.js seems to assume Symbol Set encoding here and not ZapfDingbats codes.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for inspecting it. This means that it is an issue with PDF.js, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since nobody had faced this problem I had to go with an alternative. I instead used Unicode Characters for Filled and White circles `&#9679;` & `&#9675;` and removed the radio buttons. Though the form is now not modifiable but it is good for printing purposes which was my primary concern.